# Random sampling without replacement of one variable within another variable: Using ddply() functin in {plyr} package - R

Tags: r, random, permutation, plyr, bigdata

I've been really racking my brain over this problem and with no expedient solution in sight.

I have a dataset over which I am trying to permute one variable (an attribute) within another variable (a location), irrespective of an object (an item).

Here's a snippet of the data:

```
         ID_FIELD   SPCD       Total
              1177   833  428.286591
             11383   691 1175.846712
             24081   316  137.042979
             11383   318  177.335481
              1177    71  166.629921
             24081   110 1170.012216
              1177    12    8.379811
             30284   541  585.039300
             24081   746  188.808428
             24081   531  196.142482
              1177   111   47.258113
              1177    12  198.443376
             11383   827   16.095224
```

Using `ddply()` function in the `plyr` package, with R version 3.2.0, I've submitted the following code:

```
ddply(data,.(Total,ID_FIELD),sample)
```

Here, I am trying to permute `Total` (the attribute) across `SPCD` (the item) within `ID_FIELD` (the location), and after running `ddply()` code twice in sequence, the result is the exact same as before, which is not what I want. I'd like this process randomized at each running of the function (i.e. a new shuffling of `Total` each submission of `ddply()`).

Any clues as to how to accomplish this? A speedy process would be appreciated as well, given that the application is with a large dataset. I am at my wit's end.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using plyr:

```
ddply(data, .(ID_FIELD), function(df) df[sample(nrow(df)),])
```

Using dplyr, which has a sampling function supplied:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(ID_FIELD) %>% sample_frac
```

Comment: You're permuting on the wrong fields. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for supplying these codes, but they do not resolve my problem. These codes shuffle the order of the observations by row, and they shuffle the same way in each submission of the "ddply(...)" or "data %>%..." lines. Looking at the data I've supplied above, what I'd like to do (randomly), as one example, is shuffle values of Total across SPCD within an ID_FIELD. For example, the values of Total (1175.847,16.095, and 177.335), within an ID_FIELD (11383), would shuffle among SPCD (691, 318, and 827) each time. I hope that this clarifies the problem.

Comment: You're permuting on the wrong fields. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again; I tried the updated codes, but these still do not do the trick. If it helps further, then SPCD and ID_FIELD should remain static (i.e. not move), and only values of Total should shuffle around (but those values of Total should only shuffle within its specific ID_FIELD (i.e. values of Total cannot move between different ID_FIELDs).

Comment: What's especially problematic (and mysterious) is that this code works with the data snippet above: by(data$Total, data$ID_FIELD,sample). However, that said, this code does not work with my full dataset. For some unknown reason, sum(lengths(by(data$Total, data$ID_FIELD,sample)) returns a count of total records that is ~1.25 larger than the number of total records in the original dataset. How and why this would happen? I have no idea, and it is incredibly frustrating. On the snippet of data above, sum(lengths(by(data$Total, data$ID_FIELD,sample)) returns the correct count of records. Any ideas?